# Send command line argument in Kdevelop using prompt

Tags: c++, c, kdevelop, kdevelop4

On a terminal I am able to pass command line arguments as follows

```
client -h hostname -p 3344
```

But I want to do this in KDevelop. I know how to set command line arguments using the Lauch Configuration and adding  `-h hostname -p 3344` to argument field. But my port number keeps on changing every time. Hence I want to be able to send the arguments through some console or prompt (as done in eclipse using prompt)